# In terms of grabbing audience's attention what does "prop" mean?

Tags: meaning

The video (https://youtu.be/Veg4JqsEXJo?t=22) is talking about the tips of video presentation

> ... do something to catch
>   their attention it might be using a **prop**
>   it might be jumping in off a screen

I am aware of "jumping in off a screen", though, I don't know what does "prop" mean.

Google gives these definitions

> support or keep in position.
>
> (of a horse) come to a dead stop with the forelegs rigid.

I guess neither of them could be used to grab audience's attention.

Comment: In the context of a video presentation, ***props*** are just ***visual aids***. It's basically just your *specific* context that focuses on the ***attention-grabbing*** implication. Usually, the primary allusion is to ***helping to explain*** something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prop):

> **prop** noun (IN FILM/THEATRE)
>
> [ C usually plural ]
>
> an object used by the actors performing in a play or film:
>
> *The set is minimal and the only props used in the show are a table, a chair, and a glass of water.*

Google uses the Oxford dictionary, but it often doesn't show all meanings of the word, so it's often worth it to try looking the word up on the dictionary's website.

Comment: I guess lots of things could be props, such prop gun, prop money, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 yes, those are good examples.

Comment: What it doesn't say is that _props_ is short for _[stage] properties_.